# How to change the colour of an image using a mask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I am writing a code to change the color of hair in the facial picture of a person. Doing this I made a model and was able to get a mask of the parts of the hair. But now I am stuck at a problem how to change the color of it.

Below is the output mask and input image passed.

[image]             [image]

Can you suggest me the method that could be used to change the color of the hair into different colors?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Since they both have the same shape, you can mask the image of the face using mask image. We first need to perform binary thresholding on it, so it can be used as a b&w mask. Then we can perform boolean indexing based on whether a value is `0` or `255`, and assign a new color, such as green?

```
import cv2
mask = cv2.imread('eBB2Q.jpg')
face = cv2.imread('luraB.jpg')

_, mask = cv2.threshold(mask, thresh=180, maxval=255, type=cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
# copy where we'll assign the new values
green_hair = np.copy(face)
# boolean indexing and assignment based on mask
green_hair[(mask==255).all(-1)] = [0,255,0]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(12,6))
ax[0].imshow(cv2.cvtColor(face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
ax[1].imshow(cv2.cvtColor(green_hair, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
```

[image]

Now we can combine the new image with the original using [`cv2.addWeighted`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#addweighted), which will return the weighted sum of both images, hence we'll only see a difference on the masked region:

```
green_hair_w = cv2.addWeighted(green_hair, 0.3, face, 0.7, 0, green_hair)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(12,6))
ax[0].imshow(cv2.cvtColor(face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
ax[1].imshow(cv2.cvtColor(green_hair_w, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
```

[image]

Note that you can set the weights in the weighted sum via the `alpha` and `beta` parameters, depending on how much you want the new colour to predominate. Note that, as mentioned earlier the new image will be obtained from the weighted sum `dst = src1*alpha + src2*beta + gamma`. Let's try with another colour and setting the weights as a convex combination with alpha values ranging from say `0.5` and `0.9`:

```
green_hair = np.copy(face)
# boolean indexing and assignment based on mask
green_hair[(mask==255).all(-1)] = [0,0,255]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(8,8))
for ax, alpha in zip(axes.flatten(), np.linspace(.6, .95, 4)):
    green_hair_w = cv2.addWeighted(green_hair, 1-alpha, face, alpha, 0, green_hair_w)
    ax.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(green_hair_w, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    ax.axis('off')
```

[image]

Comment: Mmm... stylish!

Comment: I believe the OP wanted to change the color of her hair, not remove it and put a green background in its place. You should be able to color the hair green by combining the color with her hair. You could use cv2.addWeighted to accomplish that.

Comment: Yes, thought about that, updated. Though the limitations are clear given the current mask @Tyson

Comment: Wow that looks good! Much better than I was expecting. Another idea could be to convert her hair to the HSV color space, change the hue a bit, and convert it back to BGR before masking it in. That might improve the dark areas of her hair from becoming too bright of a green.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. Will give it a try when I have a little more time :) thx again @Tyson

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. That was a great approach. Also, I wanted to ask why did you use ".all(-1)" in your code while masking, my code didn't work with that I had to remove that to get the same results.

Comment: Because I'm checking that all elements along the last axis (channel) are `255`. Since I've made the mask `0` or `255` valued, this sets to true those rows that are all `255`. And I index the other image on these rows, and set them to `[0,255,0]` @PrathamJindal

Comment: btw, is your approach to get the mask for the hair very *long*? If not, would you mind sharing it? @PrathamJindal

Comment: I have used a CNN trained model for it trained on the CelebAMask dataset. @yatu